# Can't load UIView from .xib file

Tags: swift, uiview, xib

I am trying to load a `UIView` from a XIB file, but it gives me this error:

> fatal error: init(coder:) has not been implemented: file /Users/Skole-Pc/Desktop/IOS-Apps/CSGO Quiz Battle/AlertView.swift, line 397

Here is my XIB file:

[image]

And here is the class that links up with the XIB file:

```
class HelpAlert: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var help1: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var help2: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var help3: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet var cancel: UIButton!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

    }

    @IBAction func help1Action(sender: AnyObject) {
        let action1 = self.action1
        // deliberately set to nil just in case there is a self reference
        self.action1 = nil
        guard let block = action1 else { return }
        block()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

}
```

And this way I'm trying to add the `HelpAlert` to my `ViewController`:

```
if let alert = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("HelpAlert", owner: self, options: nil).first as? HelpAlert {
    alert.frame = CGRect(x: CGRectGetMidX(view.bounds), y: CGRectGetMidY(view.bounds), width: view.bounds.width * 0.9, height: view.bounds.width * 0.9 * (750/650))

    view.addSubview(alert)
}
```

and thats when it gives me the error, how to I fix this?

Comment: In initWithCoder you must call super's version of initWithCoder

Comment: I'm not sure I understand that, do you possible have any code so I can see what you mean?

Comment: required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}

Comment: Juts tried that, and it gives me the exact same error

Comment: Remove fatalError statement, it doesn't make sense in this case

Comment: Thanks man that worked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Error is generated because fatalError() is called. Remove this method and call super's version of init with coder for a proper behaviour:

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
 }
```